# Best way to make my dll only accessible by my exe?

Tags: c#, security, dll, assemblies

I'm looking for a way to make my Data.dll only accessible from my exe, for security reasons.

The "[Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" method is secure? It seems that if I have other exe with the same name, I can see the objects and execute the methods marked as internal in my dll.

This is the best way? There is any other way?

Comment: No, that doesn't slow down a determined attacker much.  Using Reflection or decompiling the DLL are obvious approaches.  There's no substitute for physical security, you have to keep the DLL out of reach.  And *never* hide secrets in code.

Comment: Thank you Hans. My problem is to protect some methods that access a database, like the method to add new users, or the method that encrypts passwords. I really don't know how to protect them. Maybe compiling all in my exe and marking as internal, and them obfuscating the exe?

Comment: Then just don't do it.  Adding new users is an administrative task, it doesn't belong in a client access library.  Never manage passwords yourself, the operating system already has a highly secure way to obtain and verify them.  Leave it up to the dbase admin to leverage integrated security.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a strong name. Like that:

> [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100bf8c25fcd44838d87e245ab35bf73ba2615707feea295709559b3de903fb95a933d2729967c3184a97d7b84c7547cd87e435b56bdf8621bcb62b59c00c88bd83aa62c4fcdd4712da72eec2533dc00f8529c3a0bbb4103282f0d894d5f34e9f0103c473dce9f4b457a5deefd8f920d8681ed6dfcb0a81e96bd9b176525a26e0b3")]

from: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Note: Both the current assembly and the friend assembly must be
>   unsigned, or both must be signed with a strong name

Comment: That's what "Friend assemblies" means.

Comment: @HansPassant, But you can't get two assemblies with same strong name. i think. am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If the app requires managing users or functionality you don't want included on the DLL for security purposes, you should expose a secure web service that can authenticate the user logged into the app and perform the operations at the server level. This of course assumes that what you need to manage is shared and not specific to the client's machine.